# Javascript display a menu function and call it using while/do loop

Tags: javascript, function, do-while, prompt

```js
function displayMenu() {
  var uInput;
  var display = [1] Login\ n;
  display += [2] Add User\ n;
  display += [3] List Users\ n;
  display += [Q] Quit
  uInput = prompt(display);
  return uInput;
}

do(
  var uip = displayMenu(); alert("value of uip is: +uip")

  if (uip === "1")(
    alert("login is entered...");
  )
  else if (uip === "2")
    alert("add user entered...");
)
else
if (uip === "q")
  alert("quit is entered...");
)
) while (uip! = "q")
```

*CALL the displayMenu function and ASSIGN the captured input value to ‘uip’*
*IF ‘uip’ is equal to '1', PRINT "Login is selected.”*
*ELSE IF ‘uip’ is equal to '2', PRINT "Add user is selected."*

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Please read up on the syntax and usage of `do...while` and `if...else` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: there's error displayed in between "[1] Login\ n;" and i need to make it prompt. if i select 1, the display message would be, "Login is selected". if i select 2, the display message would be, "Add user is selected. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fendi to help us help you, please update your initial question with what you're trying to achieve, and any other relevant information like which libraries you're using.